# Kafka SimpleConsumer (Low level consumer) use cases/advantages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Only the SimpleConsumer API gives the control over from which partition each consumer retrieves data, it is said to have better offset management. Can someone explain me in detail in what scenarios this fine grain control is required over using the less complex High Level Consumer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the new consumer API is a nice combination of the Simple and High Level API sets.  The seek() and assign() methods provide the behavior you mention.

Either way, One scenario involves assigning priorities to the different partitions: partition 0 might be low priority messages and partition 1 might have high priority messages, for example.  In that case, you's want to consume messages from partition 1 before you consume any messages from partition 0.  In such a scenario, it's necessary to be able to direct Kafka to read from one specific partition.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to take full control of the consumer behavior:

- infinite retries to the broker in-case of network communication problems
- reading data from a specific topic-partition
- Your own offset management (Storing the offsets in db)
- Simplicity - It doesn't care about other consumer instances hence re-balances are not required.